# sudo: uid 1000 does not exist in the passwd file!

Tags: root, passwd

How can i restore my /etc/passwd file? I have access to it, but it's currently empty and I added this to the file, but I can't even SSH to the machine, I'm getting a "connection refused".

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
mk:x:1000:1000:mk:/root:/bin/bash
```

Is it possible to recreate the passwd file? How should it be formatted, so that I can log in again?

Thanks!

Best regards

Comment: Can you give the OS or, in the case of Linux, the distro and version that you are running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lol on the stupidity tag.  "Connection refused" usually means that sshd isn't running.  Make sure the service is running.  It may require the ssh user:

```
sshd:x:111:65534::/var/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Comment: Yeah. Well. What can I say. Stupidity big time! But... IT WORKED! Thanks a million!
But I'm still not completely up and running. Fx. I'm getting "timeout in locking authority file /root/.Xauthority". What other lines do I need for the system to function properly? Thanks in advance!